# BLE status GATT_CONN_TERMINATE_PEER_USER if BLE Server is running on Android 6

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed both BLE server and BLE client for android which work on different android device. This is how it works
1. Client connects to server
2. Data is exchanging fine
3. After a while (1 minute) connection is lost and on the client side I am getting connection status `GATT_CONN_TERMINATE_PEER_USER(19)`.

This happens only if I run the server on **Android 6**. When I am using **Android 9** I do not have this problem

Answer (score 0):

I found strange bug in **Android 6**. Which is not presented in **Android 9**.
If you have a BLE server and an active client connected and if you also have BLE scanner also working on this server phone and then in the moment if you stop scanner currently active connection is losing. On the client side you are getting `GATT_CONN_TERMINATE_PEER_USER(19)`.